# QQDVR h264 video device capture

Tags: video, directshow, video-capture, h.264, directshow.net

I have two USB video devices.

1. A Startec USB2820 usb capture
2. A 8port QQDVR h264 video capture device.

I am having all kinds of fun.   So ideally, I want to take 2 video inputs from the QQDVR capture and use them programatically to grab video from for some directshow filters.

Problems
If I use anything, the QQDVR does not show up as a video source.  I know the code is .working as it finds the Startec just fine.  the QQDVR works fine if I use their included DVR software.  The QQDVR does not show up as a crossbar device, or as a video device.

I have been using all kinds of programs from graphedit, to sample aforge, etc etc, and none of them recognize the video device.  In device manager it shows up as QQ-DVR under usb devices.   I understand these are made by the same manufacturer of easy cap.

I have been looking at AForge, DirectX.Capture, DShow.net etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Devices are all USB 2.0 as it seems. A shot in the dark is that overall bandwidth is insufficient for the fun you wanted to have.

Comment: most likely.  The stats claim it can do 30fps per channel, and I only need 2 channels.   The problem I am running into is finding a work usb capture device.  The startech doesn't work well directshow hates the crossbar device, and the QQDVR doesn't show up in graphedit or in any enumeration as a video device.

Comment: Maybe you want to connect it to different USB host controllers, if you have 2+ on your system.

Comment: if the QQDVR does not have a directshow driver, you can't use in in directshow....

Comment: Thanks Wimmel, guess I am out of luck with that card.   I was able to get the 2820 xbar working, though it seems to have interlace issues